# @Configuration inside jar not getting loaded

Tags: maven, docker, spring-boot, spring-amqp

We @Configuration file inside our project and we are adding one "xyz.jar" in class-path as maven dependency having another `@Configuration` file.

We are using one autowired bean from "xyz.jar" and when we run our project getting  following error for this bean.

"No qualifying bean of type"

We are using Spring-boot, spring-amqp and maven.

We have tried one solution to this by adding following lines to our configuration class

```
@AutoConfigurationPackage
@Import(value = XYZConfiguration.class)  //another @Configuration class from jar
```

This is working but not working when we run this jar on docker container.

Could you please help.

```
//Spring boot application class
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner
{
  private static final Logger logger =                 LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    logger.debug(" Application starting   ....");
    SpringApplication.run(VApplication.class, args);
}


@Override
public void run(String... arg0)
{
    logger.debug("Application is running....");
}
}
```

// Configuration class

```
 @Configuration
 @AutoConfigurationPackage
 @Import(value = XYZConfiguration.class)
 public class VRMQConfig
 {
  //Bean Configuration
 }
```

Docker File:

```
 FROM anapsix/alpine-java
 MAINTAINER MyService
 COPY myservice.jar /home/myservice.jar
 CMD ["java","-jar","/home/myservice.jar
```

POM file :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<plugins>
 <plugin>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 </plugin>
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
 <configuration>
    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Please add: your Spring Boot entry class (with its main), your Dockerfile (at least the CMD start command), details on how you start it when it works, your pom (except the dependencies part, want to see the "parent" section + the plugins).

Comment: thanks @Alex I have added required details.

Comment: Your Application.main calls SpringApplication.run(VApplication.class, args); is VApplication a typo ?

Comment: @Alex- it was a typo and thanks for the reply I got the issue.
The issue was with the locale and I have added commands to set locale while creating docker image.